# Twitter share button not working Uncaught Error: screenName is a required parameter

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to add simple [Twitter Share Widget](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet) as per their documentation.  I'm always getting below error on the console and button is not rendering properly. It shows as just `<a href>` link.

> widgets.js:9 Uncaught Error: screenName is a required parameter

Related javascript file (https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) is loading on dom.

Here is my code snippet

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="https://twitter.com/share" data-via="abcd">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

Comment: Are you using the code snippet provided by twitter?

Comment: What is the generated twitter code you are using?

Comment: Added code snippet to the question

Comment: I had the same exact problem since like 5 months! This issue happen randomly, sometimes it works, other not. I tried to delete all twitter related cookies, with or without AdBlock, signed out or signed in twitter, but I can't reproduce it! I really can't understand why sometimes this button doesn't load properly and only a clickable text (pure link) is showed and if I click it instead of get the share twitter pop-up I am redirect on a link like this: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.it%2F&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.it%2F

Comment: seems to be a problem related to es6-promise, https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise